Unity wont detect a mouse click whenever another button is being held down
Info

Within the game I am working on, I have 2 different abilities both bound to parts of the mouse. Ability #1 is bound to Mouse 1, and ability #2 is bound to one of the Mouse 4.
I am using the Input Manager to handle inputs.

Problem

Both abilities activate fine independently, but if I try to activate an ability while holding the other ability's button down, it will not activate.
There is nothing within the code that prevent one of the abilities from being used while the other is active, so I feel that it might be some problem with the Input System.


I haven't had many ideas on what to do to fix it, but I have fully checked the code for anything stopping them from being used simultaneously. I also made sure in Input Manager that they are both bound properly and that neither one has the other a negative button or anything like that.

please include the binding information and code as a minimal reproducible example.

as a side note, the input manager is legacy.  the new input system is much better.  new projects should favor using the new input system, unless you need to do quick debugs/testing.
